# My teacher says "is stronger and more enduring" changed the meaning. How can I write the sentence without changing the meaning?

Tags: sentence-construction, exam-questions

The instructions for a grammar exercise were to correct the following sentence:

> The camel has as much strength and more endurance than the horse.

Suggestions to correct the sentence:

1. The camel has strength as much as horse and more endurance than it.
   (This can be correct but instead of *and* using *but* is better.)
2. The camel is stronger and more enduring than the horse.
   (This is OK but the meaning is slightly changed.)

I answered somewhere as:

> The camel is stronger and more enduring than the horse.

One teacher online (who is a native speaker) said it was OK, but that the meaning is changed, so how can I rewrite it without changing the meaning?

Here is the question from my book:

[image: text of a page titled Practical Grammar showing that exercise 133 is "The camel has as much strength and more endurance than the horse."]

Without changing the meaning is not included in the original exercise.

Comment: _"The camel has as much strength as the horse and more endurance."_ Would be correct, but using _but_ is better. Because strength and endurance relate, I would write: _"The camel possesses comparable strength to that of the horse, but with greater endurance."_

Comment: @Timmetje The meaning goes indifferent  and  you used new words of your own !

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but yes, the meaning has not changed. And my suggestions are indeed formed with words of my own.

Comment: @Timmetje   not correct answer  Thank you anyway

Comment: Then your question isn't correct. I corrected the sentence without changing the meaning.

Comment: How my question is not correct ?  it is mentioned in many books and I picked as it is. Regardless to what I said ( don't change meaning ) Do as required and just correct it  >>  A Practical Grammar of the English Language: For the Use page 212 \\ The Practical Grammar: Containing Especially Such Laws of ... page 46  \\ English Composition ... - Page 32   \\ Weld's Progressive English Grammar: Illustrated with Copious . page  189 \\ The Child's Grammar: First Lessons in Language - Page 276

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142152/discussion-between-ahmad-mohammad-and-timmetje).

Comment: Please do not include images of text. They hinder searchability and accessibility. See https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/91457 and https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5364/screenshots-in-questions-what-should-we-do-to-discourage-such-behavior/5365#5365

Comment: In English, [enduring](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enduring) means *lasting* or *durable : able to exist for a long time without significant deterioration in quality or value*. [Endurance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/endurance) in this context means *the ability to sustain a prolonged stressful effort or activity*. Your sentence also said the camel was stronger than the horse when the original sentence said its strength was about the same. The change of meaning wasn't slight; it was actually quite significant.

Comment: I've edited your question to try to make it more clear that it is on-topic. It might help people see this question is on-topic if you edit your question to explain whether there are specific parts of the original sentence that you are finding difficult to express.

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" seems to be that "than" is taken to apply to both "as much strength" and "has more endurance".  But "as much strength than the horse" would be wrong.  It's not much of a problem. Indeed I don't think it is an actual error in grammar.

A solution is to bring the comparison into the first phrase:

> The camel has as much strength as the horse and has more endurance.

With "as the horse" in the first phrase that is fixed.  The second phrase has "than the horse" implied.  This is no undoubtedly correct grammar.

It would be better to use adjectives but there is no general way to "make adjectives from nouns", and there is no adjective that means "having endurance"  (I considered 'tireless', 'indefatigable' and 'unflagging', but none quite fit the sense)

So let's leave endurance as a noun

With this, we can under the simple task of changing the noun to an adjective and tidying up the syntax.  I've chosen to use the generic plural rather than the rather stilted generic "the".

> Camels are as strong as horses and have more endurance.

There are lots of other possibilities.

---

<sub>Aside, it is laughable that this claims to be "Practical Grammar", when the exercise is so *impractical*.</sub>